# html5lib Error while scraping and installation

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape data from a flight website.
This is the code I wrote:

```
todays_date = str(date.today())
arrival_filename = todays_date+"Arrival_Data_IGI.csv"
res = requests.get("https://m.newdelhiairport.in/live-flight- 
 information.aspx?FLMode=A&FLType=D")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table',{'id':'fids_row'})
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
arrival = df[0]
arrival_filename = todays_date+"_Arrival_Data_IGI.csv"
arrival.to_csv(arrival_filename)
arrival.to_csv("Arrival_Data_IGI(daily).csv")
```

But an error came when I ran the code. Error that came:

[image: Error that came]

When I tried to install html5lib using `pip install html5lib`, following error came:

[image: Installation Error]

Error while installing any library or upgrading pip.

"Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1051)'))) - skipping"

Comment: please type out the errors, in addition to the screenshots, it makes it easier to help...

Comment: First of all try to upgrade pip: `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: since you use BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml'). you should install lxml lib to parse the html file..

Comment: Have you tried  ``python -m easy_install html5lib``? Pip sometimes have issues on windows especially when using proxy network.

Comment: @MUNGAINJOROGE your solution worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade `pip`. This solution (from [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5288) github conversation) can solve the problem:

```
python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --upgrade pip
```

Comment: 1. Have you try to reinstall `pip`? 2. Do you sure you have not any local versions of pip (for example, in home directories)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, there may at times be issues when installing packages on 64-bit version.

You can download the 64-bit version of the library from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Then open Command prompt on the path where you have downloaded the file and type

```
pip install "name of the package".whl
```

Since the downloaded file is a wheel file.

Or you can download the required packages from Anaconda-Navigator.